# What's the easiest way to remove all attributes from a XML in C#?

Tags: xml, regex, parsing

I want to remove the attributes of all tags from a XML (I want to keep only the tags and their inner value). What's the easiest way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void removeAllAttributes(XDocument doc)
{
    foreach (var des in doc.Descendants())
        des.RemoveAttributes();
}
```

Usage:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path); //Or .Parse("xml");
removeAllAttributes(doc);

string res = doc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (XmlElement el in nodes.SelectNodes(".//*")) {
   el.Attributes.RemoveAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's faster if you use a better XPath like `"//*[@*]"`

```
foreach (XmlElement el in nodes.SelectNodes("//*[@*]")) {
   el.Attributes.RemoveAll();
}
```

This will limit the results to just elements that have attributes.