# Remove all XML Attributes from Atom XML

Tags: regex, xml, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, atom-feed

We are trying to remove all the attributes from our XML. The parser we use can't handle the attributes that are mentioned in the XML.

We don't think it is possible in one regex so we are looking for alternatives. 
We think that the best approach is maybe to create a regex for each tag.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<feed xml:base="https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <title type="text">Todo</title>
    <id>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/Todo</id>
    <updated>2015-11-17T10:30:34Z</updated>
    <link href="Todo" rel="self" title="Todo"/>
    <entry>
        <id>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/Todo('5')</id>
        <title type="text"/>
        <updated>2015-11-17T10:30:34Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <link href="Todo('5')" rel="edit" title="Todo"/>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SFOData.Todo"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:categoryId>5</d:categoryId>
                <d:todos m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoBean)">
                    <d:element>
                        <d:categoryId>5</d:categoryId>
                        <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDateOffSet m:type="Edm.Int32">-2147483648</d:dueDateOffSet>
                        <d:entries m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoEntry)">
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">15301</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Recruitment Request :1508 - Receptionist</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://www.example.com</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                        </d:entries>
                        <d:entryId m:type="Edm.Int32">10884</d:entryId>
                        <d:name>Ontwerp aanvraag</d:name>
                        <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                        <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                        <d:stepDescAlt>Ontwerp aanvraag</d:stepDescAlt>
                        <d:todoItemId m:null="true"/>
                        <d:url>https://www.example.com</d:url>
                    </d:element>
                    <d:element>
                        <d:categoryId>5</d:categoryId>
                        <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDateOffSet m:type="Edm.Int32">-2147483648</d:dueDateOffSet>
                        <d:entries m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoEntry)">
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">15304</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Recruitment Request : 9002 - Facility &amp; Fleet Coordinator</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://www.example.com</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">15302</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>ophanden</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Recruitment Request : 2001 - Chief Business Innovation Officer</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://www.example.com</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">15303</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>ophanden</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Recruitment Request : 2001 - Chief Business Innovation Officer</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://www.example.com</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                        </d:entries>
                        <d:entryId m:type="Edm.Int32">10905</d:entryId>
                        <d:name>Aanvraag bij Board</d:name>
                        <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                        <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                        <d:stepDescAlt>Aanvraag bij Board</d:stepDescAlt>
                        <d:todoItemId m:null="true"/>
                        <d:url>https://www.example.com</d:url>
                    </d:element>
                </d:todos>
                <d:categoryLabel>Nieuw talent rekruteren</d:categoryLabel>
                <d:displayOrder m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:displayOrder>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/odata/v2/Todo('11')</id>
        <title type="text"/>
        <updated>2015-11-17T10:30:34Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <link href="Todo('11')" rel="edit" title="Todo"/>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="SFOData.Todo"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:categoryId>11</d:categoryId>
                <d:todos m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoBean)">
                    <d:element>
                        <d:categoryId>11</d:categoryId>
                        <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-08-28T00:00:00</d:dueDate>
                        <d:dueDateOffSet m:type="Edm.Int32">81</d:dueDateOffSet>
                        <d:entries m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoEntry)">
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">14352</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Test Tester for 8050 - Technieker int Version - 3</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">14101</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Guy Londers for 8050 - Technieker int Version - 1</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">14251</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>svea huygelen for 8050 - Technieker int Version - 1</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                        </d:entries>
                        <d:entryId m:type="Edm.Int32">10004</d:entryId>
                        <d:name>Goedkeuringen aanbiedingen in behandeling</d:name>
                        <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                        <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                        <d:stepDescAlt>Goedkeuringen aanbiedingen in behandeling</d:stepDescAlt>
                        <d:todoItemId m:null="true"/>
                        <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                    </d:element>
                    <d:element>
                        <d:categoryId>11</d:categoryId>
                        <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-10-04T00:00:00</d:dueDate>
                        <d:dueDateOffSet m:type="Edm.Int32">44</d:dueDateOffSet>
                        <d:entries m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoEntry)">
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">14552</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Tom Verplancken voor 8050 - Technieker int Versie - 2</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">14551</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Nadine Martens voor 8050 - Technieker int Versie - 2</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                        </d:entries>
                        <d:entryId m:type="Edm.Int32">10224</d:entryId>
                        <d:name>Goedkeuringen aanbiedingen in behandeling</d:name>
                        <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                        <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                        <d:stepDescAlt>Goedkeuringen aanbiedingen in behandeling</d:stepDescAlt>
                        <d:todoItemId m:null="true"/>
                        <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                    </d:element>
                    <d:element>
                        <d:categoryId>11</d:categoryId>
                        <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                        <d:dueDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-10-15T00:00:00</d:dueDate>
                        <d:dueDateOffSet m:type="Edm.Int32">33</d:dueDateOffSet>
                        <d:entries m:type="Bag(SFOData.ToDoEntry)">
                            <d:element>
                                <d:completedDate m:null="true"/>
                                <d:formDataId m:type="Edm.Int64">14852</d:formDataId>
                                <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                                <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                                <d:subjectFullName>Brenda Peters for 9007 - Technical Facility Teamleader Version - 3</d:subjectFullName>
                                <d:subjectId m:null="true"/>
                                <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                            </d:element>
                        </d:entries>
                        <d:entryId m:type="Edm.Int32">10369</d:entryId>
                        <d:name>Goedkeuringen aanbiedingen in behandeling</d:name>
                        <d:status m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:status>
                        <d:statusLabel>Actief</d:statusLabel>
                        <d:stepDescAlt>Goedkeuringen aanbiedingen in behandeling</d:stepDescAlt>
                        <d:todoItemId m:null="true"/>
                        <d:url>https://hcm12preview.sapsf.eu/sf/recruiting/jobreqsummary/offerapprovals?company=DummyCompany</d:url>
                    </d:element>
                </d:todos>
                <d:categoryLabel>Goedkeuring van aanbieding</d:categoryLabel>
                <d:displayOrder m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:displayOrder>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: Why you need regex for this?

Comment: We are doing this in ABAP, ABAP is a programming language from SAP. It can't handle the Attributes in XML. The software that creates this XML is SuccessFactors, you can't change anything about the output.

Comment: What operating system are you using? It might be easier to write a utility in, say, C# to do this. [What's the easiest way to remove all attributes from a XML in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3546229/1115360) Also, you might want to let SuccessFactors know that their software produces output incompatible with ABAP, seeing as they are an SAP company.

Comment: Like they will change their entire flow just for 1 user :)

Comment: You definitely do not want to use regex for this, you want to use an XML-aware tool like XSLT. What platform should conversion run on?

Comment: Well the XML comes from odata so it's not possible to implement a middleware.

Comment: But you *are* implementing a middleware, or what does your hypothetical regex run on?

Comment: @Tomalak the regex would be run in ABAP

Comment: I don't know much about ABAP but from what Google tells me, XML parsing is perfectly possible. Maybe you try that first?

Answer (score 0):

Well... maybe this could help to you.

```
\<[a-zA-Z0-9\s\=\":\.]+\>(.*)<\/[a-zA-Z\:]+>
```

https://regex101.com/r/jL3bT7/1